# How do I split a git repository?

Tags: git

I have a git repository containing several modules, each in their own subfolder, and I'd like to split them into independent repositories, ideally preserving as much of their individual histories as possible. Is there a canonical way of doing this?

#### Exact Duplicate

[Detach (move) subdirectory into separate Git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359424/detach-subdirectory-into-separate-git-repository)